# BufferedReader inputs

Tags: bufferedreader

I have a code segment as below that uses BufferedReader to read inputs from command shell:

```
    String choice = "";

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("\nEnter choice: ");

    choice = br.readLine();
```

In this case, assuming '3' is my input, the console prints as follows:

Enter choice: 
3

I would like to know how can I make the console prints such that it appears as follows: 
Enter choice: 3

Appreciate any help!

Comment: use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `System.out.println("\nEnter choice ");`

to

`System.out.print("\nEnter choice: ");`

(`println` adds a line terminator at the end of the input string)